# Using XPATH to get the node location to retrieve another value from the same tree but not the same node

Tags: xml, xpath

I got an xml file that I need to work on (adding it in the end of the post). I need to retrieve the node “ActivityTime” only when I find the node “DocumentTypeValue” = 1319. Is there a way to look it in just one XPATH? or should I look for DocumentTypeValue ==1319 and get the current position so I can make a XPATH using the location I just retrieved? Thank you all for your help!

the file is -

```
<Document>
   <Labels>
      <Label>
         <Fields>
            <Field>
               <Code>DocumentTypeValue</Code>
               <Value>4008</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field>
               <Code>DocIDAutoNumerator</Code>
               <Value>123121</Value>
            </Field>
         </Fields>
      </Label>
   </Labels>
  <ActivityTime>2021-08-11 </ActivityTime>
</Document>

<Document>
   <Labels>
      <Label>
         <Fields>
            <Field>
               <Code>DocumentTypeValue</Code>
               <Value>1319</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field>
               <Code>DocIDAutoNumerator</Code>
               <Value>21321</Value>
            </Field>
         </Fields>
      </Label>
   </Labels>
  <ActivityTime>1993-08-11 </ActivityTime>
</Document>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to wrap your Document nodes in a single parent node, as an XML file can only have one root.

Then you can use the following XPath selector:

```
//Document[.//Field[Code[text()='DocumentTypeValue'] and Value[text()='1319']]]//ActivityTime
```

Translation: Look for any descendants of type `Document` that have a descendant of type `Field` which contains both a `Code` child with the text 'DocumentTypeValue' and a `Value` child with text '1319'. Then get the descendant of that `Document` node with type ActivityTime.

The general structure of such XPath expressions is:

```
//ParentNode[expressions to narrow down which parent node I want]//NodeIAmLookingFor[if necessary, expression to narrow down which node I am looking for]
```